# Removing escape sequences from the returned XML stream

Tags: .net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to read `XML` from an API in following way:

```
        string responseStream=null;
        try
        {
            var responseObj = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseObj.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                //responseStream = sr.ReadToEnd().Replace(@"\", "");
                  responseStream = sr.ReadToEnd();


            }
        }
```

What happens is it returns me XML in a string form but with escape sequences like `\\` `\n` in it which makes the XML invalid.

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n...
```

How can i solve this issue and get only valid XML in my string so i could pass it further to the parser.

Comment: See if [this](http://markyourfootsteps.wordpress.com/2010/10/19/escape-sequences-in-csharp/) helps you. It's quite complicated but at least should work. I'm also curious about if there is any easier way to parse and resolve escapes in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You sure that it is not just the debugger that escapes strings?

Try parsing with

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(responseStream)
```

Or even just loading the stream with

```
var document = XDocument.Load(responseObj.GetResponseStream());
```